# it accepts strings as input and add the value assigned to it but the values return zero after displaying the results

Tags: vb.net

please help me debug this code . it is a code that should accepts strings as input and calculate the value of that string using the integers assigned to the string. for example taking ABC should give the value as 33

```vb
Imports System
Imports System.Collections.Generic

Public Module Module1

    Private weights As Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
    Private addLetters As Integer

    Sub Main()


        'setup dictionary
        InitializeWeights()

        ' user input
        Dim userInput As String = Console.ReadLine()

        ' convert input to array of characters
        Dim userInputToChars() As Char = userInput.ToCharArray

        ' loop through array
        For Each character As Char In userInputToChars
            ' if character is in dictionary
            If (weights.ContainsKey(character.ToString())) Then
                ' get corresponding value from dictionary, add to addLetters
                addLetters += weights.Item(character)

            End If

        Next

        Console.WriteLine("user input: " & userInput)
        Console.WriteLine("input weight: " & addLetters.ToString())

          Console.ReadLine()
    End Sub

    Sub InitializeWeights()
        weights = New Dictionary(Of String, Integer)
        weights.Add("A", 10)
        weights.Add("B", 11)
        weights.Add("C", 12)
        weights.Add("D", 13)
        weights.Add("E", 14)
        '...
        ' do this for all letters...
    End Sub
End Module
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What do you exactly mean by debugging this code, is there any error? If yes, please share the error details on your post as well.

Comment: How about you actually debug it yourself first? Set a breakpoint at the top of the code and then step through the code line by line, examining the state at each step. As soon as the state or behaviour is not exactly what you expect, you have found an issue. You may well be able to come up with a solution yourself at that stage but, even if you can't, you can provide us with ALL the relevant information. You need to do ALL you can BEFORE posting here.

Comment: By the way, there's no need to convert the `String` to a `Char` array because a `String` is already an `IEnumerable(Of Char)` so you can make it the subject of a `For Each` loop already. Also, instead of converting the `Char` to a `String` to see whether it's in the `Dictionary`, why not put `Char` values in the `Dictionary` in the first place, i.e. `Private weights As Dictionary(Of Char, Integer)` and `weights.Add("A"c, 10)`?

Comment: *"taking ABC should give the value as 33"*. And it does, so what's the issue? You do realise that "abc" is not the same as "ABC", right?